# Printing Hello World using fewest characters

Tags: code-golf, tips, hello-world, c++

I saw a problem which asks you to print "Hello World" using the fewest characters, including spaces. How can I further shorten this code? Thank you in advance!

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){printf("Hello World");}
```

Comment: See the shortest [C++ solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55583) by [James](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31716/james) in [“Hello, World!”](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world). Note that as it is, your question doesn't meet this site's expectations so will be probably closed.

Comment: You can remove `#include <iostream>` and use `puts` instead of `printf` (assuming you're using a kind compiler that allows you to use these functions without including cstdio) (edit: it seems that neither G++ nor clang are kind enough and I was wrong) This question should almost certainly be tagged [tips].

Comment: @manatwork i tried it but i can't compile it.

Comment: @Summer, it works for me: https://pastebin.com/Qr9hM6g8 Note that as we regularly force the boundaries of compilers/interpreters, warnings are acceptable by default here.